# Make script respond to an echo from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want my AJAX script to respond to an `echo` from PHP, but it doesn't work. Here is register.php:

```php
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['username']))
  {
    require_once('dbconfig.php');
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if (strlen($user) > 1) 
    {
      echo '{"status":success}';
    } 
    else if (strlen($user) < 1) 
    {
      echo '{"status":failed}';    
    }
  } else
    echo "Sesiunea nu mai este activa.";
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnRegister').click(function() {
    var user = $('#username').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    var posting = $.post("http://localhost/univoo/ucp/universitati/dbfunc/register.php", {
      username: user, 
      password: pass
    });

    posting.done(function(data) {
      if (data.status == "success") {
        alert("Succes");
      } else if (data.status == "failed") {
        alert("failed");
      };
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your JSON response is not valid. You need to wrap 'failed' in doub'e quotes: `{"status":"success"}`. That said, it would be better if you did not build the string manually, but instead used `json_encode`

Comment: I modified and still doesn't work, and can show me how can i use json_encode ?

Comment: I would suggest you check the console for errors. If the AJAX is failing there will be an error message there which you can use to debug the problem

Comment: Ajax doesn't fail, and the response in developer tools works : {"status":"succes"}

Comment: Then try parsing the response to JSON manually. Add this as the first line in your `done()` handler: `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Thanks it works !

Comment: Glad you  got  it working. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

        require_once('dbconfig.php');
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        if (strlen($user) > 1) {
            $result = true;
        } else if (strlen($user) < 1) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = 'Sesiunea nu mai este activa.';
        }
        echo json_encode(compact('result'));
    }
?>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
posting.done(function(data) {

    var response = JSON.parse(data);

    if (response.result === true) {
        alert('success');
    } else if (response.result === false) {
        alert('failed');
    } else {
        alert(response.result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might me be on the encoding of the response. Try

```
echo json_encode('{"status":"success"}');
```

EDIT: Haha yeah my answer is wrong. Too much json encoding. Maybe JSON.parse is what is missing as stated by the comment above on your question if you are already getting the response {"status":"success"}

Comment: json_encoding JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is not valid. You need to wrap 'success' or 'failed' in double quotes, for example:

```
echo '{"status":"success"}';
```

That said, it would be better if you did not build the string manually, but instead used `json_encode` to serialize an array from your PHP logic.

Also note that your jQuery code will need to be amended to manually deserialise this text response as it will not automatically be recognised as JSON:

```
posting.done(function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data); // add this line
  if (data.status == "success") {
    alert("Succes");
  } else if (data.status == "failed") {
    alert("failed");
  };
});
```

Comment: It could be if a header of application/json is sent, no?

Comment: That's true, but given the OPs comments, that is not the case.